# Single button, Multiple image in picturebox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

This code changes the image using 2 buttons. 
How can I change the image in the picturebox using only one button? 
Is there any code to determine how many times the user already clicked the button?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1.jpg")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\2.jpg")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question about " determine how many times the user already clicked the button" is a little unclear , but i think you are referring to which picture is showing

You can do that with a if statement.

And to check the numbers of clicks you can use a dim "Dim CurPicture As Integer = 1
"
In your if statement you check the number of CurPicture  "so if 1 show picture 1"
So every time you click the button you add 1 to CurPicture

If you want to loop back to picture 1 if the last picture is showing you need to make CurPicture 1

```
Dim CurPicture As Integer = 1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If CurPicture = 1 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1.jpg")
        CurPicture = 2

    ElseIf CurPicture = 2 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\2.jpg")
        CurPicture = 3

    ElseIf CurPicture = 3 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\3.jpg")
        CurPicture = 4

    ElseIf CurPicture = 4 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\4.jpg")
        CurPicture = 5

    ElseIf CurPicture = 5 Then
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\5.jpg")
        CurPicture = 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: should i place an increment inside Button1_Click??
CurPicture += 1

Comment: @Jonathan Roque Like my code shows its in the if statement inside the button 1 click. of cores you can edit the code to something else but the increment should be in the button 1 click yes. " but of cores there are more ways to do the same , so depends what you are referring to"